# where to store "global" objects in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How or where should I store object instances that I require globally within my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721990/how-or-where-should-i-store-object-instances-that-i-require-globally-within-my-i)

I have some global object (uses in almost all Application Screens) and mostly they are created  right after application starts. I want to have access to this objects from all my ViewControllers (nothing else, only ViewControllers). Where to store it?

I think about `@property` in `AppDelegate` but i think (but I can be wrong) this is a ugly solution.

Objects can be quite complex, this is not a simple types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How or where should I store object instances that I require globally within my iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5721990/), [Global variable in iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9096712/), [Where do I create global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9593594/), [How can I save global variables in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9960982/), [iPhone Dev: global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7368820/), [Global variables in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1643467/), [Best way to keep global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3456981/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make global objects accessible by placing them in a class with class methods for accessing global objects, implementing `+(void)load` to prepare these objects, and storing them in static variables.

Header:

```
@interface GlobalObjects
+(void)load;
+(MyObject1*)myObject1;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "GlobalObjects.h"
static MyObject1* _myObject1 = nil;
@implementation GlobalObjects
+(void)load {
    _myObject1 = [[MyObject1 alloc] init];
}
+(MyObject1*)myObject1 {
    return myObject1;
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
MyObject1 *shared = [GlobalObjects myObject1];
```

You could also make the variable static inside its method for lazy initialization.

Comment: I don't understand some part. If i have a GlobalObjects class i have to implement it into all my classes? If i set it as class method there is no need to create instances in classes?

Comment: @SimpleMan All you need is to import `GlobalObjects.h`. Since all its methods are *class methods* (note the `+`) you do not need to instantiate `GlobalObjects`. The `+(void)load` method is called automatically when the class is loaded into cocoa runtime, so you do not need to call it either.

Comment: You mentioned that making the objects static uses lazy initialization, but don't all the objects get instantiated when any `[GlobalObjects <object>]` is accessed for the first time? If I'm understanding that correctly, is there a way to make objects independently lazy? 

Also, is this still the recommended way to have globally accessible objects?

Comment: @JakeT. As far as I know, the initialization has to happen at some time prior to the first access, but it wouldn't not necessarily happen immediately before the first access. The trick with the `static` that I mention in the last sentence of the answer is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11770303/335858). Another trick is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5720029/335858), but it takes a little more code.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, the second link ended up being most useful to me. Having the instance of the object that I could access rather than objects on a class seems most appropriate for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I use properties of the App Delegate, then access them by casting the sharedApplication delegate property.

```
__weak AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Hope this helps,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

@property in AppDelegate is a good solution. You could also use a singleton.

Comment: http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569940/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

You app delegate is fine if you just have a bunch of objects.

Otherwise you might build a sort of "model object" containing all of your global data.

Or, you might store them with Core Data, if they have any structure at all.

But, as I said, if you have just a couple of objects, the app delegate will just do fine.

Comment: What you mean by "if they have any structure at all". In my case this will be NSArray contains my own objects (not a simple types).

Comment: I mean, Core Data is a data base, so basically, if they have a structure that would suggest building a data base. It was just to show a full set of options, so that you can better decide which option is better for you. The question is: how are you going to access the data? An NSArray if perfect and will allow you to access objects by their index; you could use an NSDictionary and then access each object by their "name" (the dictionary key)... for more help, possibly you should give more details about your objects...

Answer (score 1):

if it's only used among view controllers, you might consider storing it in the highest level view controller which actually needs access to the shared object (when creating/pushing new controllers, set that reference counted property).

in this way, you might think of the master view controller populating the detail view controllers with their content/models.

that's really stepping away from qualification as (and burdens of) a global.

Comment: This is good advice, but following this to every view controller i have to create another instance of objects. Am i right? I want to set this objects once and get access to them from any ViewController.

Comment: @SimpleMan you would simply share the reference (to the `NSArray`) among VCs (View Controller). the array's elements would not be copied. you would need to declare new properties in your VCs for this array, but that's a lesser evil than a global `NSArray` on most days. envision it like sharing a document or model among VCs and their views. so, no, you do not need to create any additional objects (no new array, or its elements) -- but you do have to declare properties (storage) in your VCs for this shared object, and you would have to set that property when constructing/pushing the VC.