# iOS : Fail to use Global object class - Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, singleton

In my project I have an object `MainAppDataObject` that I was to use globally between all other classes. I want to keep other object in it which I need in different viewControls and can be accessed easily. I believe for this, I got to implement Singleton pattern.

I tried implementing in 2 days i.e. using AppDelegate and GlobalObjects, but cannot access in other viewController or can't set the object to be saved.

Using GlobalObjects method :
Header file :

```
@interface MC_GlobalObjects : NSObject

    +(void) load;
    +(MainAppDataObject*) sharedAppDataObject;

@end
```

Implementation File .m :

```
#import "MC_GlobalObjects.h"

static MainAppDataObject* _sharedMainAppDataObject = nil;

@implementation MC_GlobalObjects

    +(void) load {
        _sharedMainAppDataObject = [[MainAppDataObject alloc] init];
    }

    +(MainAppDataObject*) sharedAppDataObject {
        return _sharedMainAppDataObject;
    }
@end
```

In my LoginViewController.m :

```
#import "MC_GlobalObjects.h"

    MainAppDataObject *sharedAppObj = [MC_GlobalObjects sharedAppDataObject];
    sharedAppObj.authLogin = logAgent;
```

I got the above reference [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546257/where-to-store-global-objects-in-ios) , and I implemented as it says. I import MC_GlobalObjects.h, and just call sharedAppDataObject of MC_GlobalObject class. MC_GlobalObject obj is not initialized anytime nor it's method load is called. This line is the first time that I am using MC_GlobalObjects object from the start of the project.
Result of the above code : sharedAppObj is created and it has authLogin as nil (as expected). When I assign logAgent to authLogin, authLogin is created but its contents remains nil. logAgent has values in it like full_name, job_title etc properties.

Can anyone help me know, why the values of logAgent object aren't being stored in authLogin. Then I got to access authLogin in ProfileViewController.

Is anything to correct in MainAppDataObject or AgentDetails obj. MainAppDataObject.h

```
@interface MainAppDataObject : AppDataObject
{
    AgentDetails *authLogin;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) AgentDetails *authLogin;
```

Implementation File : .m

```
@synthesize authLogin;
```

AgentDEtails : .h

```
@interface AgentDetails : NSObject <NSCopying>

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *full_name;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *job_title;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *photo;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *agent_id;


    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *agentSecret;
@property (nonatomic) bool chatStatus;
    @property (nonatomic) bool onlineStatus;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *session;

-(id) initWithNSDictionary: (NSDictionary *)loginInfo;

@end
```

Implementation .m :

```
@synthesize full_name;
@synthesize job_title;
```

Where is the problem ? Can anyone please help me sort out. I got access such many objects and data across many viewControllers and other objects. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot. I have also referred other questions on the site referring the same query, but can't find a solution for the problem that I am facing. I have look around at [here], [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)[2](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html), [here](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/19/fundamental-ios-design-patterns-sharedinstance-singleton-objective-c/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546257/where-to-store-global-objects-in-ios), etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c?rq=1 for a far superior way to setup a singleton.

Comment: @rmaddy, Thanks. Can implement that in my other class where I access API's. But that doesn't give a solution for this problem. But it definitely helps in something else. Thanks for this quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. First, there's no reason to have a separate MC_GlobalObjects and MainAppDataObject classes. Make your MainAppDataObject object the singleton.

Second, you don't need to, and should not, have a +load method. Make the sharedAppDataObject method lazily load the object if it isn't loaded already:

```
@interface MainAppDataObject: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *someObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *someOtherObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someString;

+(MainAppDataObject) sharedAppDataObject;

@end
```

---

And your .m file:

```
static MainAppDataObject* _sharedAppDataObject = nil;

@implementation

+(MainAppDataObject) sharedAppDataObject;
{
  if (_sharedAppDataObject == nil)
    _sharedAppDataObject = [[MainAppDataObject alloc] init];
  return _sharedAppDataObject;
}
```

And then to use it in any class in your project, first #import the header, then use code like this:

```
[MainAppDataObject sharedAppDataObject].someString = @"Some string";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have 1 more query. I have a class APIUtility - it has methods thru which I access API's. In each view I need access to this class. It just has a key variable that is set at initial stage of app & is used to access api's. My Query - I am thinking to making this class also singleton so I don't need to create its obj in each view & also not set the key every time. Will it be advisable to create this as singleton or create a new obj in each view passing/setting the key (stored in MainApp.. probably) every time obj is created. What would be a better option. Pls Suggest

Comment: Sounds like another good situation for a singleton. Give it an instance variable for the key. Jse the same pattern I outlined above, where it has a static variable to save the single instance and return it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me decide what to do and proceed ahead. Once again Thanks.